# Setting proxy on and off, including user agent, on Ubuntu Server in Virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, virtualbox, proxy

I am setting up an Ubuntu Server VM in Virtualbox, which I plan to export/import into different environments, as follows:

1) No proxy

2) Behind a proxy server whose address is known, with no login/pwd

3) Behind a proxy server whose address is known, with no login/pwd BUT with a user-agent restriction (it allows access to the Internet with IE but not with Firefox!!

I need to know:

a) Is there some way of easily switching the proxy settings on and off for apt-get and for the command line?

b) How do I configure the user agent in the proxy settings?

c) Is it possible to change the user agent setting for Firefox so that the proxy thinks it is Internet Explorer 9?

Answer (score 0):

a) quick search of google found this which looks promising as mentioned apt-get configuration. https://askubuntu.com/questions/175172/how-do-i-configure-proxies-in-ubuntu-server-or-minimal-cli-ubuntu

b) User agent would be on the browser when you make a website request (see below) If you are asking about how to configure your proxy server to only allow specific user agents then that would be proxy specific.

c) I used to use User Agent changes a good bit for testing. Add-ons such as https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/ can be used. I haven't tested this on unix firefox but expect it will work.

Comment: Many thanks, but I think I was not clear enough. I don't want to configure the proxy but to trick it into thinking that all my http requests come from a specific user-agent. This does not necessarily mean from a browser. I first discovered this using Drupal which makes server-side requests via http for available upgrade info, and could only get around it by configuring the user agent to trick it. I will need to do the same kind of thing for apt-get